How to fix DeprecationWarning when concurrent.futures with multiprocessing.Process are used together?
How to fix the DeprecationWarning in the following pytest example? Note this is minimalistic reproducer.
Use case is rather simple:

I have an object (represented as Obj) that is tested;
Obj interacts with an external server;
For testing purposes, external server is mocked using multiprocessing.Process();
Obj uses ProcessPoolExecutor to do some CPU-bound operations;

import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import http.server
import multiprocessing

import pytest
import pytest_asyncio

# This does not work, as mock_server is not pickable...
# multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")

def hello_world():
    print("Hello, World!")

class Obj():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
        asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(self.pool, hello_world)

@pytest_asyncio.fixture
async def obj_to_test():
    return Obj()

@pytest.fixture
def mock_server(tmpdir):
    def server(path, host, port):
        os.chdir(path)
        httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(
            (host, port),
            http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
        )
        httpd.serve_forever()

    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=server, args=(".", "127.0.0.1", 9999))
    process.start()
    yield process
    process.terminate()
    process.join()

def test_something(obj_to_test, mock_server):
    # normally obj_to_test will interact here with mock_server
    pass

My environment is:
platform linux -- Python 3.12.3, pytest-8.2.0, pluggy-1.5.0
plugins: asyncio-0.23.6
I am using Python installation from this Docker image: python:3.12-slim@sha256:2be8daddbb82756f7d1f2c7ece706aadcb284bf6ab6d769ea695cc3ed6016743
pip install pytest==8.2.0 pytest-asyncio==0.23.6

After above, I am getting the following warning, which I want to fix:

/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py:66: DeprecationWarning: This process (pid=523) is multi-threaded, use of fork() may lead to deadlocks in the child.

Using multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn") does not help.
I was able to reproduce DeprecationWarning outside of pytest environment as well:
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing
import time


pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
job = pool.submit(lambda: time.sleep(5))


process = multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda: None_)
process.start()
process.terminate()

and its run:
PYTHONWARNINGS=default python3 t5.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py:66: DeprecationWarning: This process (pid=1024) is multi-threaded, use of fork() may lead to deadlocks in the child.
  self.pid = os.fork()

